# How setInterval and setTimeout behave on Phonegap/Cordova when app resumes from background?

Tags: javascript, android, ios, cordova, phonegap-plugins

If **setInterval** is set to call a function every 1 second, what happens when the app goes to background and is resumed after 30 seconds?
The function will be called 30 times in a row? setInterval will work after resume?

If **setTimeout** delay expires during background, will I receive the event on app resume? or the event will be lost?

Same behaviour for Android and iOS?